# For Google Sheets, what is the function that will populate a cell with specific text when pulling data from multiple tabs of another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am building a Google Sheet that pulls data from another Google Sheet with multiple tabs. The source sheet doesn't include one particular data point (i.e. business name), and I want to populate the cells in the corresponding rows of the new sheet based on the source tab. Is this possible? If so, what is the formula/function for doing so?

[In this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iPZ447HBWpuzFvyxqmJMU0VyHzMaBSEOj_vJd5bTwcU/edit?usp=sharing), I would like column F to be populated based on the source tab rather than manually typed. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. You have not provided any details of the source sheets. Is there a field for the "Business name"/Prescribing Partner in the source sheets, or are you anticipating taking the name from the sheet name of the import range. e.g. "JenCare - AP Prescription Form" is for the Business name - "Jencare". Would you please also summarise your research and your efforts to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: Try `vlookup()`. Your sample spreadsheet gives "Access denied."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Add an additional column to each of the IMPORTRANGE` arrays; the extra column will contain the "Business name".

For example: based on the formula in Column E,

`=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("<<insert url1>>", "CareSource Stronger Together Referral Form!e2:e1000"),arrayformula(if(len(importrange("<<insert url1>>","CareSource Stronger Together Referral Form!e2:e1000")),"CareSource",)); importrange("<<insert url2>>","JenCare - AP Prescription Form!E2:E1000"),arrayformula(if(len(importrange("<<insert url2>>","JenCare - AP Prescription Form!E2:E1000")),"Jencare",)); IMPORTRANGE("<<insert url3>>", "Focus Forward - AP Prescription Form!e2:e1000"),arrayformula(if(len(importrange("<<insert url3>>", "Focus Forward - AP Prescription Form!e2:e1000")),"Focus Forward",))}, "SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL" )`

---

**Logic**

This is the extra column:

`,arrayformula(if(len(importrange("<<insert url3>>", "Focus Forward - AP Prescription Form!e2:e1000")),"Focus Forward",))`

- if the IMPORTRANGE has a value, then create a new Column "Focus Forward".

---

**Sample**

[image: sample]

---

**Notes**

The existing spreadsheet has one formula for each column; this could be simplified by creating one formula (entered in Cell A2) that populates columns A-F. Using the example data from above, such a formula might look like this:

`=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("<< INSERT URL1>>", "CareSource Stronger Together Referral Form!a2:e1000"),arrayformula(if(len(importrange("<< INSERT URL1>>","CareSource Stronger Together Referral Form!a2:a1000")),"CareSource",)); importrange("<< INSERT URL2>>","JenCare - AP Prescription Form!a2:E1000"),arrayformula(if(len(importrange("<< INSERT URL2>>","JenCare - AP Prescription Form!a2:a1000")),"Jencare",)); IMPORTRANGE("<< INSERT URL3>>", "Focus Forward - AP Prescription Form!a2:e1000"),arrayformula(if(len(importrange("<< INSERT URL3>>", "Focus Forward - AP Prescription Form!a2:a1000")),"Focus Foward",))}, "SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL" )`